# How to change the color of reference numbers in my dissertation?

Tags: color, text-decorations, ref

The color of numbers for references is green . I need to change it to black. Any help is massively appreciated .

[image]

Comment: Please can you reproduce added a minimal compilable code? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that these links are set by `hyperref` you can put this at the end of your preamble (or anywhere *after* hyperref has been loaded):

```
    \hypersetup{citecolor=black}
```